# Cannot FTP connect to remote server using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: visual-studio, ftp, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-community

I am trying to migrate from Adobe Cloud Dreamweaver 2015 to Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community.

I wanted to do what I thought was the most basic operation and that is to select a local site on my computer then adding the FTP details to connect to the remote server. Unfortunately I get the error:

Could not connect to 'ec2-{IP address}'
Make sure that the machine name and path are valid.

These are the exact steps I have taken.

- Open Visual Studio
- Click Open Folder
- Open the folder containing the local site files on my computer
- The site files appear on the right pane under "Solution Explorer - Folder View"
- Select "Tools > Connect To Server..."
- The "Add Server" dialog appears
- Enter the IP address of the server then the error described earlier appears.

The FTP details are correct and I tested it by connecting via the browser.